# How do I count how many of each title in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to figure it out for a while now, not the best at programming. Here is what I have so far.

The keys of the dictionary should be the titles of employees in the 
list and the values the count of employees with that particular title.

```py
employees = [
    {
        "email": "jonathan2532.calderon@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 101,
        "firstname": "Jonathan",
        "lastname": "Calderon",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 3691 5845"
    },
    {
        "email": "christopher8710.hansen@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 102,
        "firstname": "Christopher",
        "lastname": "Hansen",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 5807 8580"
    },
    {
        "email": "isabella4643.dorsey@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 103,
        "firstname": "Isabella",
        "lastname": "Dorsey",
        "title": "Mrs",
        "work_phone": "(02) 6375 1060"
    },
    {
        "email": "barbara1937.baker@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 104,
        "firstname": "Barbara",
        "lastname": "Baker",
        "title": "Ms",
        "work_phone": "(03) 5729 4873"
    }
]




#my work
for i in employees:
    print(i['title'])

employees.count('title')
print()
```

```py
#my output:
Mr
Mr
Mrs
Ms
```

```
#expected output:
{'Ms': 1, 'Mrs': 1, 'Mr': 2}
```

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Where is the code that gives you the output you are describing? Put a Counter on it!

Comment: thank you for this @meowgoesthedog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter([x['title'] for x in employees])
print(counts)
# Counter({'Mr': 2, 'Mrs': 1, 'Ms': 1})
```

If there are any records that do not have a `title` field use:

```
counts = Counter([x.get("title", None) for x in employees])
# Counter({'Mr': 2, 'Mrs': 1, 'Ms': 1, None: 1})
```

Here the `.get` will get the value for `title` or return `None` if `title` isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for i in employees:
    result[i["title"]] += 1
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Mrs': 1, 'Ms': 1, 'Mr': 2})
```

Comment: Might as well use `Counter` if you are going to import from `collections`.

Comment: Very helpful, I ended up using Counter :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Counter:

```
from collection import Counter
titles = [e['title'] for e in employees]
counts = Counter(titles)
# Counter({'Mr': 2, 'Mrs': 1, 'Ms': 1})
```